# How to create horizontal slideshow for many div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm very confused to create a slideshow like this pic :
(Symbian^3 music menu)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK0F2.png

can anyone suggest me a simple code or a reference for making like this ?
looking at the pic, see the white scroll at below .when user scrolls , pictures come to center.i want st like this.

Comment: It's called "coverflow". You can get jQuery plugins to help you achieve it. Just google around.

Comment: Another name that helps searching for it is that a variant of it is often being called a 'Carousel'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something from this can help: http://pixelbell.com/jquery-image-and-content-slider-plugins/

They are mainly with javascript, but I think, that something like that can work without javascript only with new `input type range` and css3